# Hashrouter always redirecting to index

Tags: reactjs

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" render={props => <Index {...props} />} />
        <Redirect to="/" />
        <Route
          path="/staking"
          render={props => <LandingPage {...props} />}
        />
        <Redirect from="/" to="/index" />
      </Switch>
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

My url renders as http://localhost:3000/staking#/

I have to use hashrouter for github pages.

My link is the following

```
                <NavLink to="/staking">
                  <a href="/staking">
                  <i className="now-ui-icons business_bank"></i>
                  <p>Staking</p>
                  </a>
                </NavLink>react,h
```

I cannot get it to display my different page other than the index.

Comment: But but but you have redirect right after your index route :) ` <Redirect to="/" />` :)

Answer (score 0):

Your second route is Redirect to `/` which is causing every router to redirect to `/`

Remove this

```
<Redirect to="/" />
```

Also you don't need to use `<a>` tag inside `<NavLink>` since `<NavLink>` will be rendered as `<a>` and to will act as href prop.

```
<NavLink to="/staking">
   <a href="/staking">
        <i className="now-ui-icons business_bank"></i>
        <p>Staking</p>
    </a>
 </NavLink>
```

Should be

```
<NavLink to="/staking">=
   <i className="now-ui-icons business_bank"></i>
   <p>Staking</p>
</NavLink>
```

Comment: The <a> tag inside the navlink allows it be clickable. For whatever reason the link is not clickable without the <a> tag. Also, the redirect seems to have no affect. Still doesn't work.